# How to remove supersets from a list of sets using C program

Tags: c, graph

I have a   list of sets like the following in a text file. These are the output of my Code which generates paths of a graph.   Node 0 is connected with 1 and 5.Node 1 is connected with 0, 5 and 2. Node 5 is connected with 0 , 1 and 6.Thus all the nodes are connected.
The graph looks like below:

```
 0  
1 5  
2 6  
3 7  
4 8  
 9  
( source 0 , destination 9)
```

Created paths:

```
0 1 2 3 4 9  
0 1 2 3 7 8 9  
0 1 2 6 7 3 4 9  
0 1 2 6 7 8 9  
0 5 6 2 3 4 9   
0 5 6 2 3 7 8 9   
0 5 6 7 3 4 9   
0 5 6 7 8 9
```

I want to remove all the lines that are  superset (a set that contain all the elements of another set, but with additional elements) of another set.

For the example above, removing the supersets should result in the following:

```
0 1 2 3 4 9  
0 1 2 6 7 8 9  
0 1 2 3 7 8 9  
0 5 6 7 8 9  
0 5 6 2 3 4 9  
0 5 6 7 3 4 9
```

removed superset:

```
0 1 2 6 7 3 4 9   
0 5 6 2 3 7 8 9
```

How can I do this in C program. I have to accomplish this for large number of graph paths.

Comment: What if they're the same length, but different?  E.g. "0 1 2 9" and "0 2 1 9", which could happen if 1 and 2 have edges to each other.

Comment: The sample graph has been added in the question. Each node can connects to each other with 4 sides.
for example:Node 2 is connected with 1, 6 and 3.   Node 6 is connected with 5 , 2 and 7. 
 
Thus, if one path is 0 1 2 3 4 9 then another path creates 0 1 2 6 7 3 4 9 which is a superset of the first path. 
If the graph size grows( increasing row and column) these paths increase abruptly.

Comment: Is node 9 connected to both 4 and 8?  So it connects to 2 nodes above it, rather than 1?  That seems to contradict your description?

Comment: 0 and 9 are used here as source and destination. That is why 0 is connected to 1 and 2 a t the top. And 9 is connected with 4 and 8.

Comment: Ah ok, got it - the top and bottom nodes are special.

Comment: It seems to me that you want to look at adjacent pairs of rows.  The path enters the first row at some point, and exits the second row at some point.  The path through the two rows cannot contain any backtracking if it is minimal-length.  In fact, the length of the path is determined by the horizontal distance between the entry column and the exit column.

Comment: How can I remove the supersets from the outputs that have been generated? Any guideline in doing that part ?

Comment: It would be a lot easier to operate directly on the graph, rather than on the path output.  If all you have are the paths, then you've lost the information that would have made it a much easier problem.

Comment: What is the actual wording in the problem you were given?

Answer (score 0):

Consider two paths, path1 and path2, such that path2 > path1, i.e. path2 contains all nodes or path1 + some additional nodes. That means that at some node1 path2 must diverge from path1, and at some node2 later reconnect. However, because path1 does not have any nodes which are not in path2, there should be no nodes in path1 which are between node1 and node2. In other words, node2 must be located just under node1. Consequently, the only possibility for path2 to diverge from and later reconnect to path1 is to make a small loop: move one node right, one down and one left OR the symmetrical path: one left, one down, one right. So, path2 must contain the full 'square' of nodes:

```
node  node
node  node
```

The reversed is also true - if some path contains a full square of nodes, then it can be simplified by going directly down without moving left-right. So, you just need to remove all paths, which contain any square of adjacent nodes. In your example you need to remove paths which contain any of

```
1 5 2 6  
2 6 3 7  
3 7 4 8
```

Also, you must exclude paths which contain avoidable loops at the start and the end:

```
0 1 5
4 8 9
```

This solution however requires that you generate all possible paths from top to bottom. Right now you are not generating all possible paths, for example path

```
0 1 5 6 7 8 9
```

is missing.

Of course, it will be much easier just to generate paths without superset. When you generate such paths you just can't allow switching branches right under each other. Branch switches must be separated by at least one vertical move.

Comment: I believe the graph added at the beginning of the question is merely one example, and the OP desires a solution for the general case, which this answer does not address. Note the final sentence: “I have to accomplish this for large number of graph paths.”

Comment: I understood that sentence like this: there is different number of lines in the file, but always just 2 numbers per line. If there are more that 2 numbers then it will be different, of course.

Comment: Not 2 numbers in a line . there will be lots of number per line as the graph goes bigger. The example given in the question is a small graph as a sample.